# New stack with the same name as an older stack

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently submitted a new ROS repository to be indexed and have a stack (named rovio) that conflicts with an out-of-date stack on ROS. The old stack was changed from rovio to rovio-eol as seen on this wiki page: http://www.ros.org/wiki/iheart-ros-pkg After being indexed, our repository page does not list the rovio stack (because of the naming conflict I assume since http://www.ros.org/wiki/rovio still exists even though it's repository does not). Our repository page is listed at http://www.ros.org/wiki/wpi-rail-ros-pkg How can we get the current rovio stack to be indexed properly so we can begin documentation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10952/new-stack-with-the-same-name-as-an-older-stack/) by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1173 on 2011-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-08-24**:
No problem, as soon as your documentation is updated, please accept an answer to your questions, so we'll know that you are good to go.

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2011-08-23**:
My apologies. I had noticed a partial update after a few hours but did not see all of the changes and thus asked a new question. I will be sure to keep comments within the same thread in the future!

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-08-23**:
Please do not ask the same question multiple ways twice.  This is essentially the same as question 1951 that you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure this is the actual answer, but judging from this question: I'm not sure this is the actual answer, but judging from: http://answers.ros.org/question/1951/indexer-schedule

There may have been some recent issues with the indexer, but @mwise_wg seems to have resolved them.  It may take a bit of time for that to propagate.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-23**:
The rosdoc build is still inflight.